# how to display information entered by a user into a django model in the User profile

Tags: python, django, web

I'm kind of new to django, I'm working on a project currently. It is a website where people can look for houses to rent. Users will be able to create accounts, search for houses to rent and create listings about the houses they want to rent out.

I created a model to save all the information about houses that users want to rent out. I need to filter this information and display each user's listing on their profile. I have searched online but no solution yet.

Really need help.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Myhouses(models.Model):
    Available = 'A'
    Not_Available = 'NA'
    Availability = (
        (Available, 'Available'),
        (Not_Available, 'Not_Available'),
    )
    name_of_accomodation = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type_of_room = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    house_rent = models.IntegerField()
    availability = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=Availability, default=Available,)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    nearest_institution = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='author')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_of_accomodation
```

**view.py**

```
class ListingByUser(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView): 
    model = Myhouses
    template_name ='houses/ListingByUser.html'
    paginate_by = 10
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Myhouses.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^addlisting/$', views.addlisting, name='addlisting'),
    url(r'^mylisting/', views.ListingByUser.as_view(), name='ListingByUser')
]
```

**Template**

```
<ul>
{% for houses in myhouses_list %}
    <li>{{ houses.name_of_accomodation }}</li>

{%endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: No solution to what? What is wrong with the code you have posted?

Answer (score 2):

Taking a quick view of your code, there is something that stuck me on your `ListingByUser` view: you override the `get` method only to set some attributes that are normaly defined as class attributes. That also could be preventing your view to actually get your models out of the database (via calling the `get_queryset` method) and rendering a proper response.

**Edit**

I found there's also a problem linking your template to the response the `ListingByUser` view is rendering. As far as I know, Django views doesn't look into the variable `template_name` for getting the response's template. But it does call a method [`get_template_names`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.get_template_names) which returns a list of template names given as strings.

Try to modify it in this way:

**views.py**

```
class ListingByUser(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = Myhouses
    template_name ='myhouses/listing_by_user.html'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Myhouses.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)

    def get_template_names(self):
        return [self.template_name]
```

Comment: yeah.. that was actually a mistake on my part, ive corrected it but still doesn't display the user's listing on the profile page

Comment: @Gabbywells you're right. I created a Django app with your code to further investigate the problem and I also found an issue in the linking of your custom template. I recently edited the response in order to address that problem.